# How to call the function inside the api request function?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api

How do I call the function after submitting the request post API? with react js functions. Note that I already create a constructor.
How do I call the function after submitting the request post API? with react js functions. Note that I already create a constructor.

```
  fetchData() {
    request.get(
      {
        url: "http://test.com/api/employee"
      },
      function(error, response, body) {
        var bodyJson = JSON.parse(body);

        this.setState({
          username: "Empployee Table",
          result: bodyJson.data
        });
      }.bind(this)
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData(); <------- WORKS FINE
  }



  handleSubmit(event) {

    var data =  {
      employee_name:"test",
      employee_salary:"123",
      employee_age:"23",
      employee_image:"sdf",
  }

    request.post({
      url: 'http://test.com/api/insert/employee',
      form: data,

    }, function (error, response, body) {

     this.fetchData(); <------- NOT WORKING

    });

    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Code required to understand a question MUST be pasted into the question itself as text and formatted appropriately as code.  It should NOT be an external link (these are the rules here).  It should NOT be an image.  Please use the "edit" link below your question to fix it.

Comment: You will probably also need to use a more complete description of what problem you're asking about and what you're trying to accomplish.  "Call the function" does not explain what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thank you I am new here, I already edited my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not bind the callback function `this` refers to the callback context.

You can do it by using arrow function like below,

```
fetchData = () => {
    request.get(
      {
        url: "http://test.com/api/employee"
      },
      (error, response, body) => {
        var bodyJson = JSON.parse(body);

        this.setState({
          username: "Empployee Table",
          result: bodyJson.data
        });
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: can you try using arrow function with callbacks

Comment: sorry sir, but how do I do that?

Comment: it's in answer, `(error, response, body) => {
        var bodyJson = JSON.parse(body);

        this.setState({
          username: "Empployee Table",
          result: bodyJson.data
        });
      }`

Comment: use `(error, response, body) =>{...}` onstead of `function(error, response, body){...}.bind(this)`

Comment: @vincemighty I think you forgot to bind the callback in `handleSubmit`. Thats the problem

Comment: the function FetchData works fine, there's a mark there with an arrow that I am pointing at

Comment: I already bind it on constructor like this -- this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);